# Fast multiple Insert on SQL server from different threads

Tags: sql-server, performance, openjpa, apache-tomee

I have a project that involves recording data from a multiple devices (thousands) - every X seconds the device sends data that need to be recorded.

The devices send HTTP GET request to an aplication server (Apache TomEE), the server parses the request and stores it to SQL Server DB.

The TomEE servers are replicated 3 times and theres a loadbalancer that round robin requests between them.
I use OpenJPA to store the records, this way (the `em` holds the record needed to be stored):

```
    EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
    try {
        tx.begin();
        u = execute(em);
        tx.commit();
    } catch (SQLException | RuntimeException e) {
        u = handleError(e);
        if (tx.isActive())
            tx.rollback();
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
```

When I tested the performance with JMeter I found out that this architecture handle about 200 request per second - I want to make it much faster.
I thought about some directions:

1. Inserting multiple records in a single transaction can improve performance but how can I insert more than one record in a single transaction ? (they all come in different HTTP requests)
2. maybe a different configuration of the SQL server can improove performance?
3. maybe the SQL server machine needs more CPU's / Memory - how can I know if this is the bottelneck?
4. from the business logic side of view the transaction can be writen in paralel - how can I verify that te SQL server configuration is not set to one-by-one mode?

Can someone think on other direction to improve this?

Can someone recommand ways to find bottlenecks?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

best ways to go ahead are:
1) monitor the database and see its load (it is limited, middle can scale not the db).
2) take some thread stack using jstack or kill -3 on the servers to see what happens. If not enough some profiling can help but I doubt it will be useful here